# ¿Cómo saber el número de 'máscara de subred' con comado 'ip'?

Tags: linux, redes, línea-de-comandos

En sistemas GNU/Linux se ha dado de baja el comando `ifconfig`, reemplazándolo por `ip`. Para info básica de la conexión de una red suelo usar `ip` de esta manera: `ip -c addr` (la opción -c le da color a la salida).

Sin embargo, me he percatado de que no aparece el número de máscara de subred (netmask o mask), veamos una salida de `ip`:

```
wlp3s4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 44:6d:57:d0:4a:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.0.149/24 brd 192.168.0.455 scope global dynamic wlp3s4
valid_lft 286sec preferred_lft 286sec
inet6 2845:277:u270:f70:2f82:5467:f133:fef0/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
valid_lft 15559sec preferred_lft 2591989sec
inet6 fe45::51b1:dc46:151z:9p37/14 scope link 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Como pueden ver no hay referencia al número de máscara de subred. ¿Saben cómo listar el número de máscara de subred desde terminal con el comando `ip` o hacerlo de otra manera?

Comment: Si estás usando CentOS o Fedora (supongo que también RedHat), puedes instalar "yum install net-tools" (o "dnf install net-tools" segun el caso) y ya puedes hacer ifconfig otra vez.

Answer (score 8):

No lo dice explícitamente, pero puedes inferirla.

Tu IP se compone de 4 grupos decimales separados por puntos más un [CIDR](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing):

```
192.168.0.149 / 24
```

**Respuesta corta:**

Tu CIDR es 24 y esto se interpreta como "24 unos y luego puros cero"

```
11111111111111111111111100000000
```

Separándolo en 4 grupos de 8 dígitos

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
```

Convirtiendo cada grupo a decimal:

```
255.255.255.0
```

Esa es tu máscara.

**Respuesta larga:**

Dejando el CIDR de lado, cada grupo decimal representa un binario de 8 bits. Tu IP es 192.168.0.149. Los primeros 3 grupos son tu red. El último grupo eres tú dentro de la red.

```
  Red     | Tú
----------|----------
192.168.0 |  149
```

Tu IP se traduce a binario como:

```
11000000.10101000.00000000.10010101
```

Así que tu red es `11000000.10101000.00000000` y tú eres `10010101`.

El CIDR te dice cuántos números son la red y cuántos te identifican a ti. Por lo tanto, si el CIDR fuera 25 en vez de 24, eso significa "*25 unos y 7 ceros*":

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.10000000
```

En decimal:

```
255.255.255.128  // esta es la máscara
```

*ahora los 25 primeros dígitos identifican a tu red*. Sólo los últimos 7 identifican a cada equipo.

Esto significa que el rango de IPs disponibles bajó a la mitad y cada mitad es ahora una subred distinta:

```
  Subred       | hosts disponibles
---------------|----------
192.168.0.0    | 1 a 126 (127 es el broadcast)
192.168.0.128  | 129 a 254 (255 es el broadcast)
```

**¿Para qué querrías dividir tu red en dos o más subredes?**

Para una red casera, donde por ejemplo el gateway es `192.168.0.1` y el broadcast es `192.168.0.255`, probablemente nunca vas a tener 253 equipos conectados. Tal vez vas a tener menos de 60. Si al router le pones la máscara `255.255.255.192` y al DHCP le dices que asigne números entre 2 y 60, el ruteo debiera ser más eficiente (aunque probablemente ni se note).

Pero hay casos donde sí es necesario hacer esta división por una cuestión topológica (principalmente, la distancia entre subredes).

## Caso Práctico

Pensemos que eres un administrador de redes en el municipio. En realidad también te llaman cuando no les funciona el mouse, no enciende el monitor porque está desenchufado y para preguntar dónde se meten los discos de 3 1/2 porque no caben en la ranura que dice "SD". En esos momentos te gan ganas de quemar tu diploma de certificación CISCO, pero también tienes otros desafíos.

Tu municipio está separado en 4 departamentos. Cada departamento tiene entre 30 y 60 IPs tomadas (en el día los funcionarios conectan sus teléfonos, eso explica el asunto) y cada departamento dista como 900 metros uno de otro.

Un cable ethernet de 900 metros tiene demasiada pérdida y tendrías que poner repetidores en los postes del alumbrado público o algo así. Mala idea. Pero necesitas que los equipos de los distintos departamentos se vean entre sí o bien que accedan a un servidor central via intranet.

Tú sóló tienes autorización para asignar IPs de la  192.168.0.1 a la 192.168.0.255, porque la `192.168.1.x` es otro municipio y el gobierno asigna las redes disponibles para cada municipio, así que todas tus IPs empiezan con `192.168.0.<algo>` .

Por la distancia entre las reparticiones, tú decides poner un router en cada departamento. Significa que necesitas 4 subredes, lo cual significa que ahora los primeros 26 bits de la IP representan la subred y sólo los últimos 6 a cada equipo. 26 unos seguidos de 6 ceros separados en grupos de 8 y convertidos a decimal significa que la máscara es `255.255.255.192`. Esa la pones en todos los equipos y routers de los 4 municipios. (si todos los equipos obtienes su IP automáticamente via DHCP basta con que el router sepa la máscara)

Tu topología de red cambió a

```
Departamento          |  Subred       | Rango de Ips
--------------------------------------------------
Dirección de Obras    | 192.168.0.0   | 1 a 62
Dirección Áreas Verdes| 192.168.0.64  | 65 a 126
Seguridad Vecinal     | 192.168.0.128 | 129 a 190
Asistencia Social     | 192.168.0.192 | 192 a 254
```

El router en cada departamento es de Layer 2 (Capa OSI nivel 2) e identifica a los equipos de cada depto con su MAC.

Para que todos los deptos se vean entre sí, o puedan acceder a un servidor intranet central, tienes que enlazar los 4 routers a un [Switch Layer 3](https://www.lifewire.com/layer-3-switch-817583) central via fibra óptica. Este Switch Layer 3 ve a cada uno de los 4 routers Layer 2 como una VLAN y no los identifica por MAC sino por IP.

Ahora los usuarios de distintos departamentos se ven entre sí, pero si un paquete viaja entre dos equipos del mismo departamento no sale de la subred y por lo tanto el enrutamiento es mucho más eficiente. (si no te interesa que los departamentos se vean entre sí via intranet, en realidad no es necesario hacer todo esto).

También se puede dar el caso contrario. Tienes un solo departamento, 500 equipos y permiso para usar el rango de ips 192.168.0.1 a 192.168.1.255. Pones la máscara de red en 255.255.254.0. Ahora todos esos equipos pueden verse entre sí. Si hubieras dejado 255.255.255.0 los equipos `192.168.0.x` no verían a los `192.168.1.x` en su intranet, ni viceversa.

Comment: ¡ Grandiosa respuesta ! La parte donde explicas lo que es la máscara, merecería una pregunta aparte :-O

Comment: Pensaba poner sólo la respuesta corta, pero si no explicaba qué significa el CIDR y para qué se usa, en realidad sería como un axioma mágico sin respaldo teórico

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Full teoría, para saber más de lo que ocultan esos números, aunque para tener esa info habrá que sacar la calculadora ;)